# Definition of PrefixSum function

Tags: algorithms, threads, multi-tasking

I came across this [paper](https://surface.syr.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?httpsredir=1&article=1028&context=lcsmith_other) and attempting to go through the implementation of randomized selection algorithm on page 8.

Step 1 of the algorithm suggest to compute $s = PrefixSum(n_i, p)$. Where $p$ is the number of processes and $n_i$ starts simply as a number of elements in each process. Page 4 has a definition of parallel prefix, but I do not understand how to apply it in the algorithm.

Example, let $n_1 = 5, p = 2$, what is $PrefixSum(5,2)$?

Thank you.

Comment: Prefix sum is a very common operation in parallel algorithms, so there are many sources covering it. Did you check out any others, like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum)?

Comment: @Juho The only reasonable idea I came up with is similar to Wikipedia, i.e For process $P_2$, $PrefixSum(n_2, p) = n_1 + n_2$, but I am not sure whether that's correct, since this calculation is not a function of p, as in $PrefixSum(n_i, p) = n_1 + ... + n_i = f(i)$